# c# delegate progressbar multithread and class in class

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, delegates

I got my Winform(Class A) which uses Class B and
Class B uses Class C

Class C does stuff for me which reads word documents and retrieves data and pastes it in an excel file.
I made a seperate Thread for that, so i can still move the winform around.

Now i want my progressbar to view the value of which file it is working on from 0 to amountoffiles.

It only updates while the form is the Active window.

I got this currently in class C. Which i give the progressBar as parameter from Class A to B to C.

```
private void SetValue(int value)
{
    // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
    // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
    // If these threads are different, it returns true.
    try
    {
        if (this.pbar.InvokeRequired)
        {
            if (Doc_converter.Form1.ActiveForm != null)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetValue);
                Doc_converter.Form1.ActiveForm.Invoke(d, new object[] { value });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.pbar.Value = value;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //To do
    }
}

delegate void SetTextCallback(int value);
```

Is there a different way to get this done?

Or a delegate from Class C to Class A?

Keep in mind that it's a different thread than the form thread.

Edit: Forgot to mention that i can only use .NET 4.0 or lower because the application has to run on a windows xp machine.

Comment: In .NET 4.5 you can use the Progress<T> class to send a progress message from a background Thread to the UI thread, thus avoiding both `Invoke` *and* coupling of the background class with the form. What .NET version are you using?

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.0 because it has to run on a windows XP machine.

Comment: You can add the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` Nuget package to get `async/await` and `Progress` support as long as you have VS 2012+. This shouldn't be an issue now that VS 2013 Pro is free

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that, Currently using VS2012. So it should be possible.

Comment: Added an example as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET 4.5 or in .NET 4.0 with the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) package, you can use the [Progress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to send progress messages (actually full-blown objects) from one thread to another. Events are raised on the thread that created the initial Progress object (specifically, on the SynchronizationContext where object creation happened), so you don't need to use `Invoke` at all.

You should create a Progress object on the UI thread and pass it to the background processing class as an `IProgress` interface. Each time the background thread calls `Report`, the appropriate callback will be called in the form, eg:

On  the form:

```
private void ReportProgress(Tuple<int,string> progress)
{        
    pbar.Value=progress.Item1;
    status.Text=progress.Item2;
}


public void StartProcessing()
{
    IProgress<Tuple<int,string>> progress=new Progress<Tuple<int,string>>(ReportProgress);

    var workerClass=new MyWorkerClass();
    workerClass.DoWork(progress);
    ....
}
```

and in the worker class:

```
public void DoWork(IProgress<Tuple<int,string> progress)
{
    for (int i=0;i++;i<1000)
    {
         if (i%10==0)
         {
             progress.Report(Tuple.Create(i/10,String.Format("Now at {0}",i);
         }
    }
}
```

The example is of course contrived, and I could have used `Progress<int>` instead of `Progress<Tuple<int,string>>` but this demonstrates that the Progress object can send complex objects as messages, not just an integer.

Passing `Progress` as an `IProgress` interface is mandatory, because `Progress` explicitly implements `IProgress.Report`. This way you can't get a dependency on the specific implementation even if you wanted to lazily pass `Progress` to the worker